# Which regular expression requires backtracking?

Tags: regex, backtracking

There are three different solutions to implement regular expression matching: DFA, NFA and Backtracking. I am looking for examples:

- a regexp, which can be solved with a DFA and the reason, why a DFA is sufficient.
- a regexp, which requires a NFA and the reason why a NFA is necessary.
- a regexp, which requires backtracking and the reason why backtracking is necessary.

A recommendation for some good literature about this topic would be nice, too.

Comment: I think you'll have better luck asking this on [cstheory.se].

Comment: I think this chapter in Mastering Regular Expressions might be of help http://oreilly.com/catalog/regex/chapter/ch04.html

Comment: @NarendraYadala The link is broken

Comment: A related (but different) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57731835/why-does-regexp-have-a-timeout-method-while-in-theory-they-shouldnt

Answer (score -3, accepted):

What I found out so far is:

- Every regular expression, which can be implemented with a NFA, can also be implemented with a DFA. Every NFA can be transformed into a DFA.
- Regular expressions, which require backtracking, are regular expressions, which contain back references like `/(a)\1/`.

Answer (score 4):

i guess there is more than 1 meaning to the word **backtracking** - even `'.*a'` has to backtrack to match the string `"lalaiiiiiii"` *(because* `.*` *will first match the whole string - so then* `a` *won't match anything - and only then it will give up one character at a time, so the final match would be* `"lala"`*)*

i highly recommend http://www.regular-expressions.info/