# In regular expressions, what is a backtracking / back referencing?

Tags: regex

What does it mean to use a regular expression backtracking?

Also, could you provide an example of this?

Comment: Assuming *backtrace* = backtracking, similar question: [Which regular expression requires backtracking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132412/which-regular-expression-requires-backtracking)

Comment: There are some good examples with full explanation on http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Backreferences and backtracking are two different things. The former is using the results of a capture later in code, e.g.

```
(['"]).*?\1
```

This will match a single- or double-quoted string (ignoring escapes for the moment). It uses a backreference to refer to the open symbol (the single or double quote) so it can match that at the end.

Backtracking, on the other hand, is what regular expressions do naturally during the course of matching when a match fails. For example, if I'm matching the expression

```
.+b
```

against the string

```
aaaaaabcd
```

then it will first match `aaaaaabc` on the `.+` and compare `b` against the remaining `d`. This fails, so it backtracks a bit and matches `aaaaaab` for the `.+` and then compares the final `b` against the `c`. This fails too, so it backtracks again and tries `aaaaaa` for the `.+` and the matches the `b` against the `b` and succeeds.

Comment: One more detailed answer can be found at https://community.appway.com/screen/kb/article/checking-strings-avoiding-catastrophic-backtracking-1482810891360#:%7E:text=Catastrophic%20backtracking%20is%20a%20condition,the%20string%20to%20not%20match