# What is the "unit" of pcre.backtrack_limit?

Tags: php, preg-replace, backtracking

I'm encountering an issue where `preg_replace()` with a complicated regular expression causes an error (`PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR`) due to `pcre.backtrack_limit` being too low, which is set to `1,000,000` by default. I set this to `10,000,000`, and it works for this particular application.

My question is, what exactly is `backtracking limit`'s, loosely defined, "unit"? Does the `1,000,000` figure correspond to memory size? If not, what does it signify? I'm trying to understand what a reasonable setting for this on my environment.

Reference on `preg_replace`:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php#ini.pcre.backtrack-limit

Reference on backtracking:
[In regular expressions, what is a backtracking / back referencing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011592/in-regular-expressions-what-is-a-backtracking-back-referencing)

Comment: First of all, what you are asking here is not about a “unit” – that’s something like a mile or a kilogram, but there is no unit involved here, it’s just a plain number. And it sets the limit for backtracking attempts before giving up on a search that is becoming to complex/memory expensive.

Comment: You've just answered my question. "Number of backtracking ATTEMPTS" is a unit :). If you could provide a link with a reference to this, I'd be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: As an aside comment, If you have this kind of error, I suggest you to rewrite your pattern instead of changing the backtrack_limit.

Comment: @Casimir, I'm not sure if I can post it here, unfortunately. It's not mine. I was just more interested in what the PHP setting was about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the PCRE source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/6053987bc27e8dede37f437193a5cad448f99bce/ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_exec.c#L722), this error is returned when "match()" is called more than 1,000,000 times recursively:

```
/* First check that we haven't called match() too many times, or that we
haven't exceeded the recursive call limit. */

if (md->match_call_count++ >= md->match_limit) RRETURN(PCRE_ERROR_MATCHLIMIT);
```

That is converted into a "PHP_PCRE_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR" error [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/a770d29df74515197c76efdf1a64d9794c27b4af/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c#L64).

According to the pcreapi manpage (see https://serverfault.com/a/408272/140833 ):

> Internally, PCRE uses a function called match() which it calls
>   repeatedly (sometimes recursively). The limit set by match_limit is
>   imposed on the number of times this function is called during a match,
>   which has the effect of limiting the amount of backtracking that can
>   take place. For patterns that are not anchored, the count restarts
>   from zero for each position in the subject string.

I think that the unit is therefore something like "Number of backtracking attempts". I'm not sure that it's 1-to-1 with that though.

Here's a demo isolating the error case with a simple "[Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)" regex:

```
<?php

ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit', 100);

for ($len = 1000; $len <= 1001; $len++) {

    $x = str_repeat("x", $len);
    $ret = preg_match("/x+x+y/", $x);

    echo "len = " . $len . "\n";
    echo "preg_match = " . $ret . "\n";
    echo "PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR = " . PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR . "\n";
    echo "preg_last_error = " . preg_last_error() . "\n";
    echo "\n";
}
```

Run this code here: https://3v4l.org/EpaNC, to get this output:

```
len = 1000
preg_match = 0
PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR = 2
preg_last_error = 0

len = 1001
preg_match = 
PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR = 2
preg_last_error = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this will help : 
According to [pcre's source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/a770d29df74515197c76efdf1a64d9794c27b4af/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c#L64) this error code comes when pcre triggers an PCRE_ERROR_MATCHLIMIT. 
And according to [this changelog](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/1e3452992fac7536d30a92955b20b8af038f1ef7/ext/pcre/pcrelib/ChangeLog#L2052) of pcre, this is probably your fault because your regex is probably causing a memory leak.

I could suggest to review your regex as a best way to solve your problem, otherwise, if you insist to make it work, you can do (but i don't recommend) smoething like this :
    ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit', PHP_INT_MAX);

[edit]
i believe this setting is all about pcre's heavy processing capabilities, that's why i suggest to review you regex to try to make it lighter (split in into multiple regexes, add more iterations on your data, etc...)

Comment: "this is probably your fault because your regex is probably causing a memory leak." -- I think that changelog entry refers to a specific bug that has been addressed. It is possible to trigger this error with a correct regex that uses too much backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

This `ini_set("pcre.backtrack_limit", "5000000");` worked for me.
I placed this at the beginning stage of my mpdf page and within 1:04 minutes my 276 pages document was generated.