# How to find all the words that begin with a|b and end with a|b. (Ex: “adverb” and “balalaika”)

Tags: regex, perl

The following perl program has a regex written to serve my purpose. But, this captures results present within a string too. How can I only get strings separated by spaces/newlines/tabs?

The test data I used is present below:
http://sainikhil.me/stackoverflow/dictionaryWords.txt

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub print_a_b {
    my $file = shift;

    $pattern = qr/(a|b|A|B)\S*(a|b|A|B)/;
    open my $fp, $file;

    my $cnt = 0;
    while(my $line = <$fp>) {
        if($line =~ $pattern) {
            print $line;
            $cnt = $cnt+1;
        }
    }
    print $cnt;
}

print_a_b @ARGV;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider using an [anchor like `\b`: word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

That would help apply the regexp only after and before a word.

```
 \b(a|b|A|B)\S*(a|b|A|B)\b
```

Simpler, as [Avinash Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297613/avinash-raj) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942492/how-to-find-all-the-words-that-begin-with-ab-and-end-with-ab-ex-adverb-an/38942509?noredirect=1#comment65240034_38942509):

```
(?i)\b[ab]\S*[ab]\b
```

(using the [case insensitive flag or modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html))

Comment: KISS `(?i)\b[ab]\S*[ab]\b`

Comment: More clearer form `(?i)(?<!\S)[ab]\S*[ab](?!\S)`, "How can I only get strings separated by spaces/newlines/tabs?"

Comment: @AvinashRaj I always try to avoid first lookaheads (positive, negative), but depending on the source material, it can make sense. At least there is no backtracking involve, apparently.

Comment: Hi @AvinashRaj: Thanks for the reply. How is it working exactly?

Comment: @saint1729 test both the regexes in this site https://regex101.com/r/pV4iU3/1 . You should find the difference..

Comment: @saint1729 on the (?<!\S) syntax, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind

Comment: `(?<!\S)` - Asserts that the match Not preceeded by a non-space  character. `(?!\S)` asserts that the match not followed by a non-space character.

Comment: Okay. Thank You :)

Comment: qr/^a.*a$/ is a regular expression that matches all lines that start and end with a. Is there a any generic way to find all the lines that begin and end with the same characters?

Comment: @saint1729 -  Generic = `(?m-s)^([a-z]).*\1$`

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple words in the same line then you can use word boundaries in a regex like this:

```
(?i)\b[ab][a-z]*[ab]\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

The pattern code is:

```
$pattern = /\b[ab][a-z]*[ab]\b/i;
```

However, if you want to check for lines with only has a word, then you can use:

```
(?i)$[ab][a-z]*[ab]$
```

Update: for your comment * lines that begin and end with the same character*, you can use this regex:

```
(?i)\b([a-z])[a-z]*\1\b
```

But if you want any character and not letters only like above you can use:

```
(?i)\b(.)[a-z]*\1\b
```

Comment: Is there a any generic way to find all the lines that begin and end with the same character? Not just 'a' or 'b'

Comment: @saint1729 use [backtrack](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9011592/995714). `\b([ab])\S*\1\b`

Comment: @saint1729 I've updated the answer with the regex for your comment