# Regular Expression: Backtracking in Possessive Quantifier

Tags: java, regex, string, quantifiers

I was reviewing a test and noticed that a possessive quantifier actually worked in an `str.split()`. so I wrote the following code:

```
String str = "aaaaab";

if(str.matches("a*+b"))
    System.out.println("I backtrack");
else
    System.out.println("Nope.");
```

When run, this prints out `I backtrack`. Here's why this is confusing, I've been told that a possessive quantifier never backtracks, so why would `a*+` give up the `b` in the String?

What I want is a more detailed explanation of when possessive quantifiers backtrack.

Comment: Why would the ``a*+`` consume the ``b``? That's the only scenario in which backtracking would happen. But it doesn't.

Comment: Try it with `.*+b` vs `.*b` (or `[ab]*+b` vs `[ab]*b` if you want to be more specific)

Comment: A link: http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no backtracking in your example.

You are saying "any number of `a` characters". So, the engine will collect those 5 `a` chars and then stop; to then find the `b`.

That is all there is to this.

Backtracking means that the engine has to "track back" after collecting *too much* of the input string; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011592/in-regular-expressions-what-is-a-backtracking-back-referencing) for an example of that.

And beyond that: your if condition returns **true** when the pattern matches the input. Your conclusion that this means "it is backtracking" is not correct:

A match is a match; no matter if the engine had to backtrack in order to match (or not). In other words: your little test there doesn't tell you anything (it only tells you if the input matched the given pattern; period).