# Regex string matched failure

Tags: regex

I do not understand how regex string matching works

```
r2 = r'a[bcd]*b'
m1 = re.findall(r2,"abcbd")
abcb
```

This falls in line with what was explained in [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

Step 3 The engine tries to match b, but the current position is at the end of the string, so it fails.

How?I do not understand this?

Comment: This is called *backtracking*.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011592/in-regular-expressions-what-is-a-backtracking-back-referencing But I really don't get your question :(

Comment: Look and play with your regex: https://regex101.com/r/rAJLc0/5. You have error in "step 3" - The engine includes in match last b in abcbd, and stops. It is not failure, you have found a substring that matches.

Comment: See also [this post of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869557/can-i-improve-performance-of-this-regular-expression-further/33869801#33869801), it might help you understand how regexes with quantifiers work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression requires the match to end in `b`, therefore everything is matched up to the trailing `d`. If `b` were optional, as in `a[bcd]*b?`, then entire string would be matched.

Answer (score 4):

The following regex `a[bcd]*b` matches the longest substring (because `*` is greedy):

- `a` starting with `a`
- `[bcd]*` followed by any number (0: can match empty string) of character in set (b,c,d)
- `b` ending by `b`

EDIT: following comment, backtracking occurs in following example

```
>>> re.findall(r2,"abcxb")
['ab']
```

- `abc` matches `a[bcd]*`, but `x` is not expected
- `a`   also matches `a[bcd]*` (because empty string matches [bcd]*)
- finally returns `ab`

Concerning greediness, the metacharacter `*` after a single character, a character set or a group, means any number of times (the most possible match) some regexp engines accept the sequence of metacharacters `*?` which modifies the behavior to the least possible, for example:

```
>>> r2 = r'a[bcd]*?b'
>>> re.findall(r2,"abcbde")
['ab']
```

Comment: If you want to make your answer a solution, you must explain the meaning of "greedy" and how `*` is related to backtracking.