# Why does this regex pattern not match?

Tags: php, regex, match, backtracking, quantifiers

Regex101 link: https://regex101.com/r/MsZy0A/2

I have the following regex pattern; `.++b` with the following test data; `aaaaaaaacaeb`.

What I don't understand is the "Possessive quantifier". I've read that it doesn't backtrack, which it normally does. However, I don't think it has to backtrack anyways? It only has to match anything up to and including "b", "b" would be matched twice, as `.+` matches everything (including "b"), and the "b" after would also match "b".

Could someone please explain the possessive quantifier's role in this?

This question is not a duplicate of the one noted, I'm asking about this particular case because I still didn't get it after reading the other answer.

Comment: I have never seen such a pattern, but `(.+)+b` works just fine.  So does `.+b`.

Comment: Why would you have to +? What is the second + supposed to do?

Comment: Since possessive quantifier doesn't backtrack `.++` matches everything including last `b` hence last `b` never matches

Comment: @anubhava Thanks! That makes sense ️

Comment: @Galen Not a dupe, I'm asking about this particular case =)

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5319978/3540693) is amazing! Read it and you will understand it

Comment: I actually read that one before posting this, it makes sense now, but my dumb brain didn't get it before hahahahaha

Comment: @g3mini I see. In that case, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9011951/8955448). It has a nice explanation of backtracking. Notice where it says backtracking would occur. This is what the possessive quantifier prevents, so the match fails. In your example, the `.++` immediately matches the whole `aaaaaaaacaeb`, so there is nothing left for the following `b` to match without backtracking.

Comment: In your example you have `.+` and this match with all the string. Then it try to match with the `b` but the matcher doesn't have more string to check because `.+` has match with all the string and doesn't remain more characters. Because the possessive quantifier doesn't backtrack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`++` Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, without giving back - means, if you write `.++`, it matches everything including the final `b`. So the additional `b` in your regex will never matched.

You could get around this, if you don't use possessive quantifiers or simply remove the `b` from the matching class `[^b]++b` - but I would suggest the first. Possessive quantifiers are almost everytime unneccessary.

Comment: yeah but what do you do if there are one or more `b` in the middle of the string... I **don't** think that `[^b]++b` **will work properly**... Going for `.+b` would be better?

Comment: As wenn sonst know, what he actually want to schiebe, I cant tell you, whats really the best solution

Comment: yeah that's why I voted +1 :-)

Comment: _Possessive quantifiers are almost everytime unneccessary_ citation needed. I don't agree with this, often found them (and atomic groups) very helpful. The rest  of the answer is fine :)