# Matching 3-digit-groups in a string using regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl

This is what I am trying to do :

> Given a string, 12345678, commify(str) should give me 12,345,678.

The problem is to be solved using regex with Perl, and the solution that works for this problem is this :

> s/(?<=\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/,/g

**Source** : Mastering Regular Expressions

The problem I am having in understanding this is how we are able to capture the "345" part of this string. One thing that I could think about is that the regex pointer "i" ( this is how I am visualising it ) starts at 1, another pointer "j" traverses the entire string and finds the appropriate location between 5 and 6. Then i moves to 2. "j" traverses the entire string again, finds the appropriate position between 2 and 3(since now a comma has been inserted between 5 and 6).
Is my understanding correct ? If not, could anybody help me to visualise this process ?

Note : I have found similar questions but they don't seem to explain how the problem is solved but rather state the exact answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert commas into number string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721304/insert-commas-into-number-string)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The linked question just asks *how* to do it. This question starts with the regex provided in answers to the other question and asks *why* the regex works.

Comment: It doesn't help that your regex is *wrong*. That substitution leaves the string `12,`. Your second (capturing) group should be a look-ahead instead to avoid deleting digits.

Comment: @Borodin, Sorry , edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(?<=\d)(\d\d\d)+(?!\d)
```

how it works, reading from the right :

- `(?!\d)` lookahead assertion ensures there is no digit just after this point, the cursor (in input) is is just after the last digit
- `(\d\d\d)+` matches 1 or more groups of three digits
- `(?<=\d)` ensures there is still a digit before the first digit of a group

update about backtracking: taking 123456789

first engine starts whenever it find a digit before cursor : after 1

```
1.23456789
```

then it tries to match at least 1 and as many group of three digits

```
1.234.567.89
```

after 89 it fails to find a third digit, also backtracking it can't match because of negative lookahead, so it backtracks at the begining and goes to the following character : 2

```
12.345.678.9
```

again it fails to find a second digit within a group of three so it goes to 3

```
123.456.789
```

now there is no more digit so it matches.

Note that the worst case is when numbre is a multiple of 3, and it is what it is done for each replacement because the lookahead not move forward the input cursor.

including perl one-liner

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=\d)(?=(\d{3}(?{print "matched $&.\n"}))+(?!\d(?{print "failed: $&.\n"})))/,/g'  <<<123456789
```

Comment: My bad. Corrected

Comment: But by that logic, shouldn't only match 678 ( the last 3 digits ) ? The cursor should be at the position between 5 and 6 to insert the comma. As i understand, the regex pointer should only move forward from here. Is that not right ?

Comment: i've just seen that [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vlHBeB/1/) provides also a debugger maybe can help clicking on regex debugger below tools

Comment: at (\d\d\d)+ (?!\d), regex engine can choose between two paths : if next character is a digit (it must match three if there's less than three it must backtrack), else (it's not a digit) match is done

Comment: The text I was referencing did not introduce backtrack , so thank you for that. I am referencing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011592/in-regular-expressions-what-is-a-backtracking-back-referencing . Backtracking should happen when the regex fails to find a match. However, the regex would find a match at the very end ( last 3 digits ) and should stop. Why did it go back ?

Answer (score 3):

Adding thousands-separating commas to a number is inherently the kind of thing which is easier to do from right to left, because one counts in this direction.  The algorithm for the reversed number is simple: replace every group of three numbers by those three numbers followed by a comma.  In the code snippet below I use this reverse trick, and then reverse the amended number again at the end.

```
$s = "12345678";
print $s . "\n";
$t = reverse $s;
$t =~ s/(\d{3})/${1},/g;
$s = reverse $t;
print $s;

12345678
12,345,678
```

### Demo

Answer (score 3):

This is simple way to get the data

```
$num=12345678;
$num =~ s/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(\D|$))/$1\,/g;
print $num;
```