# How grep selects a pattern for a line if several patterns match one line at once, and they intersect

Tags: grep

Consider this example.
I write `grep -e aboba -e ba test/test4.txt`. In this file I have only one line: `aboba aboba aboba aboba aboba baboba`. I thought grep traversed all regular expressions in a specific order. Those. For each line, it first considers the first regular expression, then the next one, and so on. [image]

However, in this example my logic broke down. grep will recognize the first 5 words as `aboba`, and in the last word it will find two occurrences of `ba`. Why is that? It seems to me that the result should be either `aboba` 6 times, or `ba` in the first 5 words, and `ba` 2 times in the last word.

Comment: As stated in Paul Hodges' answer, you could resort to [look-ahead/look-behind syntax](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), e.g. `echo 'aboba baboba babeba' | grep -P --color -e 'aboba|ba(?!boba)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `aboba` the first letter of the word starts a match on one of the patterns(`aboba`). The parser tracks that match through each letter, registers it, then moves on to the next character until it fails, or confirms a complete match - in this case, `aboba` matches.

In `baboba` the first letter of the word starts a match on one of the patterns(`ba`). The parser tracks that match through each letter, registers it, then moves on to the next character until it fails, or confirms a complete match - in *this* case, the match was **ba**.

Having completed a match that can't be part of a longer match it starts over at the next character, and the next character is `b`, which might be a *new* match(of `ba`), so it checks `o` and fails. AFAIK, backtracking won't re-enter a marked-as-finished pattern without lookbehind, so it continues to the next character, another `b` - the first character of another possible `ba` match.

It continues to find a `a`, completing a match for another **ba**, registers that, and continues to the next character.

This process effectively *consumed* the first `a` of the possible `aboba` in a successful match of `ba`, so most implementations never bother to check for the possibility of overlapping patterns without explicit lookahead/lookbehind.

(The amount of backtracking that might trigger could exponentially increase the work it would have to do, as well as radically complicating the CLI options needed to establish which behavior the user *wanted*, not to mention that a large number of patterns - you can load *big* files of possible matches to be searched - might leave the program backtracking and testing one record till the heat death of the universe, never mind the possible *millions* of records `grep` is commonly asked to scan...)

So as far as I know, no overlaps without lookahead or lookbehind, or custom implementations.
c.f. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/how-to-use-regex-to-find-all-overlapping-matches) for a couple of examples.

Consider the way your given patterns interact, and look at these examples:

```
$: grep -o -e ababa -e ba <<< abababababaabababa
ababa
ba
ba
ba
ababa
ba

$: grep -o -e xxx -e xxxx <<< xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxx
xxxx
xxxx
xxx
```

Comment: [This discussion of backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011592/in-regular-expressions-what-is-a-backtracking-back-referencing) might help.

Comment: Also c.f. [Catastrophic Backtracking](https://community.appway.com/screen/kb/article/checking-strings-avoiding-catastrophic-backtracking-1482810891360), this [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-backtracking-in-regular-expressions) on backtracking, and [this explanation of lookahead and lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: How can you implement this yourself? It's just that my goal is to make my own version of grep that will work the same way as the original version. How can i do this?

Comment: Let’s say, I just already have in my program all the expressions that need to be found. How should I organize such a search? I'm using regex.h in C

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understood what had to be done. Previously, I simply went through all the regular expressions in a loop, because of this, they were searched for me in a certain order. But it turns out that it was necessary to combine them into one large regular expression through the symbol "\|"

Comment: I wouldn't reinvent the wheel unless it's an assignment. :)