How does regex decide when to backtrack?
As far I understood, on match failure, regex backtracks to the previous closest choice, chooses the next alternative and continues matching. Is it true that regex avoids backtracking, in case there is no possibility of a match ?
Here is a scenario, I am unable to explain to myself this regex101 debugger output.
Regex: ^(?<Major>0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(?<Minor>0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(?<Patch>0|[1-9][0-9]*)$
Input string: 1.222222222222.33333333333.0
Why does the above regex backtrack at the end, when there is no chance that $ will match an avoided [0-9]? After the patch group is exhausted, will it avoid backtracking the ([1-9][0-9]*) part for Minor and Major? If so, how and why?
If anyone has a better example to showcase how regex decides to backtrack or not, it would be appreciated.
Edit 1: why did Regex assumed that $ could be found by backtracking for [0-9]* ?
is this dependent on type of regex engine? if yes what should be best practice to avoid this kind of backtracking.

Strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011592/in-regular-expressions-what-is-a-backtracking-back-referencing (check some of the links in question's comments). Especially the website regular-expressions.info

In theory it always backtracks until it is at the start of the regex pattern without any remaining options. Regex engines may have several optimisations, but this is really implementation dependent.

I, for one, don't know. But I do know that this depends on the regex engine - both on what type of engine is in general, and depends on the particular implementation too. Long ago I read a book, its title is Masteting regular expressions. Really dense, and it covers backtracking too:
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-regular-expressions/0596528124/

"in case there is no possibility of a match" - how would it know that without trying?

In theory, this is how the match occurs:
00000000001111111111222222222
01234567890123456789012345678
1.222222222222.33333333333.0


^ matches 0 chars at position 0.

0 doesn't match at position 0. ⇒ Backtrack
[1-9] matches 1 char at position 0.

[0-9]* matches 0 chars at position 1.

\. matches 1 chars at position 1.

0 doesn't match at position 2. ⇒ Backtrack
[1-9] matches 1 char at position 2.

[0-9]* matches 11 chars at position 3.

\. matches 1 chars at position 14.

0 doesn't match at position 15. ⇒ Backtrack
[1-9] matches 1 char at position 15.

[0-9]* matches 10 chars at position 16.

$ doesn't match at position 26. ⇒ Backtrack


[0-9]* matches 9 chars at position 16.

$ doesn't match at position 25. ⇒ Backtrack


…
[0-9]* matches 1 char at position 16.

$ doesn't match at position 17. ⇒ Backtrack


[0-9]* matches 0 chars at position 16.

$ doesn't match at position 16. ⇒ Backtrack








[0-9]* matches 10 chars at position 3.

\. doesn't match at position 13. ⇒ Backtrack


[0-9]* matches 9 chars at position 3.

\. doesn't match at position 12. ⇒ Backtrack


…
[0-9]* matches 1 char at position 3.

\. doesn't match at position 4. ⇒ Backtrack


[0-9]* matches 0 chars at position 3.

\. doesn't match at position 3. ⇒ Backtrack












^ doesn't match at position 1. ⇒ Backtrack
^ doesn't match at position 2. ⇒ Backtrack
…
^ doesn't match at position 27. ⇒ Backtrack
^ doesn't match at position 28. ⇒ Backtrack
Failed to match.

In practice, there can be optimizations as long as the result is the same.
For example, an optimizer could analyze the pattern and see that the string must contains exactly two . to match, and start the matching process by counting the number of . in the string.
Perl's engine doesn't go that far — the cost of performing such an analysis could eclipse the gains — but it does look for a . before even starting to match.
$ perl -Mre=debug -e'
   "1.222222222222.33333333333.0" =~
      /^(?<Major>0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(?<Minor>0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(?<Patch>0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/
'
…
Matching REx "^(?<Major>0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(?<Minor>0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(?<Patch>"... against "1.222222222222.33333333333.0"
Intuit: trying to determine minimum start position...
  doing 'check' fbm scan, [1..25] gave 1
  Found floating substr "." at offset 1 (rx_origin now 0)...
  (multiline anchor test skipped)
Intuit: Successfully guessed: match at offset 0
   0 <> <1.22222222>         |   0| 1:SBOL /^/(2)
   0 <> <1.22222222>         |   0| 2:OPEN1 'Major'(4)
   0 <> <1.22222222>         |   0| 4:BRANCH (buf:1/1)(8)
   0 <> <1.22222222>         |   1|  6:EXACT <0>(14)
                             |   1|  failed...
   0 <> <1.22222222>         |   0| 8:BRANCH (buf:1/1)(14)
   0 <> <1.22222222>         |   1|  10:ANYOFR[1-9](12)
   1 <1> <.222222222>        |   1|  12:STAR(14)
                             |   1|  POSIXA[\d] can match 0 times out of 2147483647...
   1 <1> <.222222222>        |   2|   14:CLOSE1 'Major'(16)
   1 <1> <.222222222>        |   2|   16:EXACT <.>(18)
   2 <1.> <2222222222>       |   2|   18:OPEN2 'Minor'(20)
   2 <1.> <2222222222>       |   2|   20:BRANCH (buf:2/2)(24)
   2 <1.> <2222222222>       |   3|    22:EXACT <0>(30)
                             |   3|    failed...
   2 <1.> <2222222222>       |   2|   24:BRANCH (buf:2/2)(30)
   2 <1.> <2222222222>       |   3|    26:ANYOFR[1-9](28)
   3 <1.2> <2222222222>      |   3|    28:STAR(30)
                             |   3|    POSIXA[\d] can match 11 times out of 2147483647...
  14 <22222> <.333333333>    |   4|     30:CLOSE2 'Minor'(32)
  14 <22222> <.333333333>    |   4|     32:EXACT <.>(34)
  15 <2222.> <3333333333>    |   4|     34:OPEN3 'Patch'(36)
  15 <2222.> <3333333333>    |   4|     36:BRANCH (buf:3/3)(40)
  15 <2222.> <3333333333>    |   5|      38:EXACT <0>(46)
                             |   5|      failed...
  15 <2222.> <3333333333>    |   4|     40:BRANCH (buf:3/3)(46)
  15 <2222.> <3333333333>    |   5|      42:ANYOFR[1-9](44)
  16 <222.3> <3333333333>    |   5|      44:STAR(46)
                             |   5|      POSIXA[\d] can match 10 times out of 2147483647...
  26 <3333333333> <.0>       |   6|       46:CLOSE3 'Patch'(48)
  26 <3333333333> <.0>       |   6|       48:SEOL(49)
                             |   6|       failed...
  25 <333333333> <3.0>       |   6|       46:CLOSE3 'Patch'(48)
  25 <333333333> <3.0>       |   6|       48:SEOL(49)
                             |   6|       failed...
  24 <33333333> <33.0>       |   6|       46:CLOSE3 'Patch'(48)
  24 <33333333> <33.0>       |   6|       48:SEOL(49)
                             |   6|       failed...
  23 <3333333> <333.0>       |   6|       46:CLOSE3 'Patch'(48)
  23 <3333333> <333.0>       |   6|       48:SEOL(49)
                             |   6|       failed...
  22 <333333> <3333.0>       |   6|       46:CLOSE3 'Patch'(48)
  22 <333333> <3333.0>       |   6|       48:SEOL(49)
                             |   6|       failed...
  21 <33333> <33333.0>       |   6|       46:CLOSE3 'Patch'(48)
  21 <33333> <33333.0>       |   6|       48:SEOL(49)
                             |   6|       failed...
  20 <33333> <333333.0>      |   6|       46:CLOSE3 'Patch'(48)
  20 <33333> <333333.0>      |   6|       48:SEOL(49)
                             |   6|       failed...
  19 <.3333> <3333333.0>     |   6|       46:CLOSE3 'Patch'(48)
  19 <.3333> <3333333.0>     |   6|       48:SEOL(49)
                             |   6|       failed...
  18 <2.333> <33333333.0>    |   6|       46:CLOSE3 'Patch'(48)
  18 <2.333> <33333333.0>    |   6|       48:SEOL(49)
                             |   6|       failed...
  17 <22.33> <333333333.>    |   6|       46:CLOSE3 'Patch'(48)
  17 <22.33> <333333333.>    |   6|       48:SEOL(49)
                             |   6|       failed...
  16 <222.3> <3333333333>    |   6|       46:CLOSE3 'Patch'(48)
  16 <222.3> <3333333333>    |   6|       48:SEOL(49)
                             |   6|       failed...
                             |   5|      failed...
                             |   4|     BRANCH failed...
                             |   3|    failed...
                             |   2|   BRANCH failed...
                             |   1|  failed...
                             |   0| BRANCH failed...
Match failed
…

Also note how it results in less backtracking than the unoptimized approach above.
(Note that you used PCRE2 and not Perl on regex101.)

Is it true that regex avoids backtracking, in case there is no possibility of a match ?

The depends entirely on the engine, the string and the pattern.

why did Regex assumed that $ could be found by backtracking for [0-9]* ?

That question makes no sense. You actually want to know the following:

why didn't the Regex realize that $ couldn't be found by backtracking for [0-9]* ?

Still an invalid question. Failing to match doesn't backtrack through [0-9]*. It backtracks through (?<Patch>A|B). If it was just [0-9]* before $, Perl's engine would actually be smart enough to skip the backtracking.
$ perl -Mre=debug -e'
   "1.222222222222.33333333333.0" =~
      /^(?<Major>0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(?<Minor>0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(?<Patch>0$|[1-9][0-9]*$)/
'
…
Matching REx "^(?<Major>0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(?<Minor>0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(?<Patch>"... against "1.222222222222.33333333333.0"
Intuit: trying to determine minimum start position...
  doing 'check' fbm scan, [1..25] gave 1
  Found floating substr "." at offset 1 (rx_origin now 0)...
  (multiline anchor test skipped)
Intuit: Successfully guessed: match at offset 0
   0 <> <1.22222222>         |   0| 1:SBOL /^/(2)
   0 <> <1.22222222>         |   0| 2:OPEN1 'Major'(4)
   0 <> <1.22222222>         |   0| 4:BRANCH (buf:1/1)(8)
   0 <> <1.22222222>         |   1|  6:EXACT <0>(14)
                             |   1|  failed...
   0 <> <1.22222222>         |   0| 8:BRANCH (buf:1/1)(14)
   0 <> <1.22222222>         |   1|  10:ANYOFR[1-9](12)
   1 <1> <.222222222>        |   1|  12:STAR(14)
                             |   1|  POSIXA[\d] can match 0 times out of 2147483647...
   1 <1> <.222222222>        |   2|   14:CLOSE1 'Major'(16)
   1 <1> <.222222222>        |   2|   16:EXACT <.>(18)
   2 <1.> <2222222222>       |   2|   18:OPEN2 'Minor'(20)
   2 <1.> <2222222222>       |   2|   20:BRANCH (buf:2/2)(24)
   2 <1.> <2222222222>       |   3|    22:EXACT <0>(30)
                             |   3|    failed...
   2 <1.> <2222222222>       |   2|   24:BRANCH (buf:2/2)(30)
   2 <1.> <2222222222>       |   3|    26:ANYOFR[1-9](28)
   3 <1.2> <2222222222>      |   3|    28:STAR(30)
                             |   3|    POSIXA[\d] can match 11 times out of 2147483647...
  14 <22222> <.333333333>    |   4|     30:CLOSE2 'Minor'(32)
  14 <22222> <.333333333>    |   4|     32:EXACT <.>(34)
  15 <2222.> <3333333333>    |   4|     34:OPEN3 'Patch'(36)
  15 <2222.> <3333333333>    |   4|     36:BRANCH (buf:3/3)(41)
  15 <2222.> <3333333333>    |   5|      38:EXACT <0>(40)
                             |   5|      failed...
  15 <2222.> <3333333333>    |   4|     41:BRANCH (buf:3/3)(48)
  15 <2222.> <3333333333>    |   5|      43:ANYOFR[1-9](45)
  16 <222.3> <3333333333>    |   5|      45:STAR(47)
                             |   5|      POSIXA[\d] can match 10 times out of 2147483647...
  26 <3333333333> <.0>       |   6|       47:SEOL(48)
                             |   6|       failed...
                             |   5|      failed...
                             |   4|     BRANCH failed...
                             |   3|    failed...
                             |   2|   BRANCH failed...
                             |   1|  failed...
                             |   0| BRANCH failed...
Match failed
…


is this dependent on type of regex engine?

Yes.

if yes what should be best practice to avoid this kind of backtracking.

Formulate the pattern so that it only backtracks on failure (except trivially to determine the correct alternate), and prevent backtracking. In Perl, preventing the backtracking can be achieved using the "possessive quantifier" (+) or an "independent subexpression" ((?>PATTERN) or (*atomic:PATTERN)).
^
(?<Major> 0 | [1-9][0-9]*+ )
\.
(?<Minor> 0 | [1-9][0-9]*+ )
\.
(?<Patch> 0 | [1-9][0-9]*+ )
\n?+
\z

$ perl -Mre=debug -e'
   "1.222222222222.33333333333.0" =~
      /^(?<Major>0|[1-9][0-9]*+)\.(?<Minor>0|[1-9][0-9]*+)\.(?<Patch>0|[1-9][0-9]*+)\n?+\z/
'
…
Matching REx "^(?<Major>0|[1-9][0-9]*+)\.(?<Minor>0|[1-9][0-9]*+)\.(?<Patc"... against "1.222222222222.33333333333.0"
Intuit: trying to determine minimum start position...
  doing 'check' fbm scan, [1..25] gave 1
  Found floating substr "." at offset 1 (rx_origin now 0)...
  (multiline anchor test skipped)
Intuit: Successfully guessed: match at offset 0
   0 <> <1.22222222>         |   0| 1:SBOL /^/(2)
   0 <> <1.22222222>         |   0| 2:OPEN1 'Major'(4)
   0 <> <1.22222222>         |   0| 4:BRANCH (buf:1/1)(8)
   0 <> <1.22222222>         |   1|  6:EXACT <0>(18)
                             |   1|  failed...
   0 <> <1.22222222>         |   0| 8:BRANCH (buf:1/1)(18)
   0 <> <1.22222222>         |   1|  10:ANYOFR[1-9](12)
   1 <1> <.222222222>        |   1|  12:SUSPEND(18)
   1 <1> <.222222222>        |   2|   14:STAR(16)
                             |   2|   POSIXA[\d] can match 0 times out of 2147483647...
   1 <1> <.222222222>        |   3|    16:SUCCEED(0)
                             |   3|    SUCCEED: subpattern success...
   1 <1> <.222222222>        |   1|  18:CLOSE1 'Major'(20)
   1 <1> <.222222222>        |   1|  20:EXACT <.>(22)
   2 <1.> <2222222222>       |   1|  22:OPEN2 'Minor'(24)
   2 <1.> <2222222222>       |   1|  24:BRANCH (buf:2/2)(28)
   2 <1.> <2222222222>       |   2|   26:EXACT <0>(38)
                             |   2|   failed...
   2 <1.> <2222222222>       |   1|  28:BRANCH (buf:2/2)(38)
   2 <1.> <2222222222>       |   2|   30:ANYOFR[1-9](32)
   3 <1.2> <2222222222>      |   2|   32:SUSPEND(38)
   3 <1.2> <2222222222>      |   3|    34:STAR(36)
                             |   3|    POSIXA[\d] can match 11 times out of 2147483647...
  14 <22222> <.333333333>    |   4|     36:SUCCEED(0)
                             |   4|     SUCCEED: subpattern success...
  14 <22222> <.333333333>    |   2|   38:CLOSE2 'Minor'(40)
  14 <22222> <.333333333>    |   2|   40:EXACT <.>(42)
  15 <2222.> <3333333333>    |   2|   42:OPEN3 'Patch'(44)
  15 <2222.> <3333333333>    |   2|   44:BRANCH (buf:3/3)(48)
  15 <2222.> <3333333333>    |   3|    46:EXACT <0>(58)
                             |   3|    failed...
  15 <2222.> <3333333333>    |   2|   48:BRANCH (buf:3/3)(58)
  15 <2222.> <3333333333>    |   3|    50:ANYOFR[1-9](52)
  16 <222.3> <3333333333>    |   3|    52:SUSPEND(58)
  16 <222.3> <3333333333>    |   4|     54:STAR(56)
                             |   4|     POSIXA[\d] can match 10 times out of 2147483647...
  26 <3333333333> <.0>       |   5|      56:SUCCEED(0)
                             |   5|      SUCCEED: subpattern success...
  26 <3333333333> <.0>       |   3|    58:CLOSE3 'Patch'(60)
  26 <3333333333> <.0>       |   3|    60:SUSPEND(70)
  26 <3333333333> <.0>       |   4|     62:CURLY{0,1}(68)
                             |   4|     EXACT <\n> can match 0 times out of 1...
  26 <3333333333> <.0>       |   5|      68:SUCCEED(0)
                             |   5|      SUCCEED: subpattern success...
  26 <3333333333> <.0>       |   3|    70:EOS(71)
                             |   3|    failed...
                             |   2|   BRANCH failed...
                             |   1|  BRANCH failed...
                             |   0| BRANCH failed...
Match failed
…

Backtracking is sometimes needed, but most backtracking can be eliminated in this manner.

There went your weekend...

This is just a common sense answer but AFAIK, there are many different implementations of and algorithms for regex matching.
In this case it seems to me that when the algorithm first fails to match the $, it starts backtracking, because one of the previous matching groups might have matched and thus consumed a newline (because regex matching is greedy by default, i.e., every expression tries to eat as many characters as it can) and perhaps if that newline were used to match the $, the characters before it could match the rest of the expression.
Us humans see that there are no newlines in the string to match and that no part of the regex could match one anyway but apparently, the algorithm doesn't notice that.
Consider modifying your regex so that the last matching group allowed for newlines:
^(?<Major>0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(?<Minor>0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(?<Patch>0|[1-9\n][0-9\n]*)$

If you passed this into the new regex:
1.222222222222.33333333
333.0

it would first try to put all the 3s into the last group. Then it would fail on the final .0, because it doesn't match the $, so it could backtrack and match the $ to the newline between the 3s and the first line would match the whole regex. Ta-da!
You can see it in action here:
https://regex101.com/r/snqyOe/1
EDIT 2 (in response to another comment)
Note that the new regex wouldn't work as a replacement for OP's original one, it's just an example meant to illustrate when it makes sense for the regex algorithm to backtrack.
EDIT (in response to comment):
This particular algorithm backtracks, because the authors of that regex implementation decided to do it that way, maybe to make it obvious how it worked for educational purposes.
Brian Kernighan mentions a regex-matching algorithm that never backtracks (in the sense of going back character by character), because it remembers all possible matches of all the subregexes it encounters (see A Regular Expression Matcher).
Another approach is to match regexes by identifying the subregex that is the easiest to match, looking for a match of that and then working from there to the left and to the right to see if it actually matches.

Thanks @eltomito , Your example has perfect regex behavior as of my understanding.

But I am still not sure why regex decided "previous matching groups might have matched and thus consumed a newline" i.e ($ might have been consumed by [0-9]) . I am concerned for this regex behavior. As it does unnecessary backtracking.

(?0|[1-9\n][0-9\n]*)$ is wrong. Did you mean (?<Patch>0$|[1-9][0-9]*$)?

@LastKnightXZ I edited my answer to try to explain why it backtracks.

@ikegami It isn't wrong, it works in the online regex tool that OP links to. See here: https://regex101.com/r/snqyOe/1

@eltomito Your testing was insufficient. It is wrong because it matches the string produced by "1.2.\n3" even though it shouldn't. (Note that I didn't downvote, though I would appreciate it if you fixed the error. I provided the corrected version in my earlier comment.)

@ikegami I don't see that as a problem. It isn't meant to match or not match your example string, it's just meant to illustrate the point of a greedy subregex making it necessary to backtrack.

Re "it's just meant to illustrate the point", No it wasn't. You suggested it as a replacement for the OP--"Consider modifying your regex"--but it won't work as a replacement for the OP because it's not equivalent. Why are you resisting fixing your bug instead of fixing it? Doing so wouldn't take away from the point you wanted to illustrate, while providing a simpler pattern that's useful to the OP, all without the distraction of being buggy!

@ikegami Okay, I think I get your point now. I didn't use your regex, because I find the construct $|(something) too contrived. It's just my personal preference but I'd never use it and I find it hard to understand. What I did IMHO makes it clear that it matches any number or a newline. But you are right, I should point out it matches different things.

Then at least use (?<Patch>0\n|[1-9][0-9]*\n). The main problem is the \n in [1-9\n]. Though I think changing $ to \n ruins your point.

@ikegami Why is the \n in [1-9\n] a problem?

See my second comment, above.
