# Why does Regexp have a timeout method, while in theory they shouldn't?

Tags: regex, regular-language, computation-theory, dfa

This is a theoretical Computer Science question (Computation Theory).

I know that RegExps can take a very long time to calculate. However, from Theory of Computation we know that matching with a Regular Expression can be done extremely fast in a few clock cycles.

If RegExps are equivalent to Finite Automata, why RegExps have (or require) a timeout method?
Using a DFA, the computation time for matching can be exteremely fast.

By RegExps I mean the Regular Expressions pattern matching classes in major languages; JavaScript, C#, etc.

Are common RegExps ("regex"s) not equivalent to the Regular Expressions in Theory of Automata (i.e. Regular Languages)?

For examples see: [How do I timeout Regex operations to prevent hanging in .NET 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616435/how-do-i-timeout-regex-operations-to-prevent-hanging-in-net-4-5) and [Regex Pattern Catastrophic backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751230/regex-pattern-catastrophic-backtracking) .

If Regexp's matching require Backtracking, it means they are not equivalent to Regular Expressions.

If the languages captured by "Regexp"s are not Regular Languages, historically why (out of which necessity) were they extended?

If it that  the resulting DFA will require a huge set of states?

Comment: Normally matching is fast, but there are some cases with certain regular expressions  and long input that can cause it to be very slow.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question. This is a theoretical question.

Comment: Then it doesn't belong on [so], which is about practical programming problems. Theoretical questions belong on [cs.se]. Also, the mathematics of regular languages belongs in [math.se].

Comment: RegExp objects have more features than a DFA. All a DFA can do is accept/reject. But RegExp objects also report captures. Recovering captures requires more work.

Comment: Recovering captures should not take that long one a match (accept/reject) is done.

Comment: I suspect two possible reasons: 1. because the string can be any substring, i.e. when not surrounded  `/^` and `$/` . 2. Because the state space (number of the states of the resulting DFA) can easily grow extremely large.

Comment: @Barmar  OK but theoreticians may not know about details of common (Perl,etc) RegExp classes.

Comment: This question is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132412/which-regular-expression-requires-backtracking?rq=1 However, it is not asking this question (about distinction of classes).

Comment: Your question isn't about Perl, you tagged it `nsregularexpression`, which is from the Apple library used for Objective C and Swift.

Comment: @Barmar Please re-read the question and unmark it. It has nothing to do with the redirected question (the example can be useful but it is asking a different question).

Comment: In fact, I don't think timeouts are common to most regular expression implementations. AFAIK there's no timeout in PHP or Python.

Comment: But the point remains, the reason you need a timeout is because some regular expressions cause catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: Also, modern regular expressions like PCRE are not equivalent to DFAs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good reason is [catastrophic backtracking](https://regular-expressions.com/catastrophic.html?wlr=1), which explains why matching of some regexes will not return before the [heat death of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe).

Comment: This link seems to explain the reason that is the answer to my question. However, your answer does not mention it.

Comment: I know (and it was mentioned in the question that) it can be computationally expensive. I wanted to know why, i.e. which feature of the `RegExp`s cause this, despite claiming be REs, i.e. despite `RegExp` sharing its name with Regular Expressions in classic Theory of Computation.

Answer (score 0):

Because regex are not equivalent to the Regular Expressions in Theory of Automata.

They are more like cousins with extra functionalities that make them more complex and sometimes (depending on the regex) impossible to execute on long strings.

Comment: This is the sort of answer I need. However, is the above statement correct?

Comment: But what particular extra functionalities make them non-RE (as in Theory of Automata)?

Comment: Without that, the answer is incomplete.

Comment: The correct answer take a CS paper or book. There are certain regex that can be converted, but for example (A*)B\1 till I know can not be converted to a Regular Expression in theory of automata. Check this short text : https://www.rexegg.com/regex-vs-regular-expression.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Patterns_for_non-regular_languages

Answer (score -1):

> *(out of which necessity) were they extended?*

Regexp implementations were extended in systems in which the lack of a regexp feature requires difficult workarounds, such as writing a substantial amount of code in an inexpressive programming language. There is also the grave risk that the code might turn out to be correct, performant and robust against false positive matches.